# How do I run the play-scala demo?

Tags: scala, playframework

I've downloaded the [Scala demo code](https://github.com/playframework/play-scala) for Play Framework.

I can compile it. All the unit-tests pass. Now how do I actually run this thing?

Comment: Please read the documentation first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sbt` or `activator`, then `run`.
[image]
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PlayConsole